# how to get time based on country in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
select getdate()
```

If we write this it gives server time, but I want the time based on country. Specifically, if I operate from India it should show time in India, and if I operate from Canada it should show time in Canada.

Comment: You can do this from your client side, it will be more simple.And what do you mean by operate from India ? are you taking about the website is opened from india location ? or the sql database is hosted in India based server?

Comment: website from India

Comment: what is the front end you are using ?

Answer (score 2):

use `AT TIME ZONE`

```
select getdate() AT TIME ZONE 'India Standard Time'
```

So you can easily set parameter for timezone and can get the local timezone datetime

Comment: have u read the question correctly ? this code will give only indian timezone . He want the time based on the country which operates

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV yap this will return for indian time but you can parameterize  time zone parameter  from request is coming to server

Comment: you forget to include that in the answer

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near 'TIME'.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV I am useing  sql server 2012

Comment: try to use SELECT 
SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+05:30') and the last paremeter you can change for getting different timezones

Comment: @ganesh the At timezone only will work with sql server 2016 +

Answer (score 1):

For someone using SQL Server < 2016

```
SELECT 
SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+05:30')
```

So you can replace the time_zone values for getting different timezone times.

Another example with USA Pacific timezone

```
SELECT 
SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '-08:00')
```

You can see the timezone details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zones_by_country)